# Testing view on Rails 4 mountable engine with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails

i'm working on a mountable engine based on rails4 with rspec testing framework. I built a simply app through 'r g scaffold post title content'. Everything worked fine except view testing. When i executed rake app:spec:views, it always say:

> "  Failure/Error: render
>        ActionView::MissingTemplate:
>          Missing template posts/indexwith {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif,
>   :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form,
>   :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder,
>   :raw, :ruby]}. Searched in:
>            * "/projects/_plugins/blorgh4m_rspect/spec/dummy/app/views"
>            * "/projects/_plugins/blorgh4m_rspect/app/views" "

so i change "render" to "render template: "blorgh4m_rspect/posts/show", the error became

> " Failure/Error: render template: "blorgh4m_rspect/posts/index"
>        ActionView::Template::Error:
>          undefined method `post_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000000427cb40>:0x00000004ff97f0>
>        # ./app/views/blorgh4m_rspect/posts/index.html.erb:21:in`block in
>   **home_elbbub**_works_projects__plugins_blorgh_m_rspect_app_views_blorgh_m_rspect_posts_index_html_erb__569958834415291959_42058840'
>        # ./app/views/blorgh4m_rspect/posts/index.html.erb:15:in `each'
>        # ./app/views/blorgh4m_rspect/posts/index.html.erb:15:in`**home_elbbub**_works_projects__plugins_blorgh_m_rspect_app_views_blorgh_m_rspect_posts_index_html_erb__569958834415291959_42058840'
>        # ./spec/views/blorgh4m_rspect/posts/index.html.erb_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in ' "

it looks like all the routes path helpers are invalid.

Has anybody met this kind of case? and do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to namespace your routes. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes

```
engine_name.post_path
```